# Finding the curvature from a set of datapoints

Tags: matlab

I have a set of

1. 1-d
2. 2-d

data. I want to find the curvature at each single point. Until now I was using difference technique to find out the curvature, i.e, central difference at middle and forward and backward difference at the ends. I am writing the code in Matlab.

The problem is curvature is supposed to bring out a sudden change in dataset at a particular location. What happens is it only shows abrupt change in curvature at the starting and end of the region. But within the region it shows smooth transition?

Any ideas?

Comment: Some example input and output and desired output data would be helpful...

Comment: "the curvature at **each single point** [...] central difference at **middle**..." ?? I think the description of your problem and formulation is unclear. As Dan said, you need to provide sample data and code to explain your problem.